# How can I get this condition to work properly?

Tags: discord.py

The intention was to when -rickroll is used and the bot is pinged it should say no u if not | update-> the user is the one who has to be pinged.

The it should send a gif and say (@the pinged) has been rickrolled lol

````
    if user.id != 878176818564317184:
        await ctx.send('https://tenor.com/view/rick-astley-rick-roll-dancing-dance-moves-gif-14097983')
        await ctx.send(user)
        await ctx.send('has been rickrolled lol')
    else:
        await ctx.send('No u')```
````

Comment: Could you include the definition of `user`?

Comment: Could you also include in what way it isnt working and the test you have done to narrow down the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    #refering to the message sent in discord and chaning it to lower case
    msg = message.content.lower().replace(' ', '')
    if msg.startswith('!help'):

        if message.author.id != 878176818564317184:
            await message.channel.send('''https://tenor.com/view/rick-astley-rick-roll-dancing-dance-moves-gif-14097983''')
            await message.channel.send(f'''{message.author.mention} you have been rickrolled lol''')
        else:
            await message.channel.send('No u')
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing `ctx` is the first parameter of the discord.py `on_message` event, then the variable `ctx` is an instance of the [**discord.message.Message**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message) class which contains no method called `send`, thus `ctx.send(user)` is not going to work.

Assuming you want your bot to respond in the same text channel the message was sent to, you can take advantage of the [**channel**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.channel) attribute from the **Message** class, which contains a `send` method that will allow you to send messages.

Therefore a possible solution would be:

```py
await ctx.channel.send("Your message")
```

A different but less usual approach would consist on the usage of the [**Message.reply**](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.reply) method. It would be like this:

```py
await ctx.reply("Hey, I'm replying to your msg!")
```

The biggest difference between the two would be that the second uses Discord's **reply** feature, hence the user who sent the message in first place would be pinged.

You can find this and more information in the [official documentation of the library](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).